# Apache Wicket 7 - Application properties

Tags: java, wicket

Fairly new to Wicket so excuse my ignorance.

I have a Wicket app...starts with `WicketApplication.class`  I have a `WicketApplication.properties` file to load some values. The properties file sits next to the class file (same package). Works fine, no issues.

Now, I would like to move the properties file outside the application WAR/JAR. Exported the app as a WAR to run on Tomcat. I have create a a folder called `properties` under tomcat root & moved WicketApplication.properties to this directory. Added the following to init() method in WicketApplication.class...

```
String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        realPath = realPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
        if (realPath.toUpperCase().indexOf("WEBAPPS") != -1) {
            String newRes = realPath.substring(0,  realPath.toUpperCase().indexOf("WEBAPPS") -1);
            System.out.println (newRes + "/properties");
            getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().add(new Path( newRes + "/properties"));
        }
```

I get an exception thrown.

How do I "externalise" the properties file?

Also, if I could take one step further, how do I map a properties file name to class name..it, *`myapplication.properties -> WicketApplication.class`*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new IStringResourceLoader with `application.getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(...)`.
See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/515e2be2a5301f5caf7b1baee4a593d21c20e275/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/ResourceSettings.java#L220-L224 for the default ones.

`IResourceFinder` should be used when you want to add custom location for your HTML files.

There is no way to map `myapplication.properties` to `WicketApplication.class`. By adding an additional IStringResourceLoader you just tell Wicket to search in yet another place.

Comment: Hi _martin-g_ Thanks for your response & clarification. I had been trying `IResourceFinder` to define location of prop files. Will try `IStringResourceLoader` as suggested.